# How to use ng-repeat to show all items in the same line

Tags: angularjs, node.js

I'm doing a M.E.A.N stack application and I need to show all tags about one article in the same line or the same row. Also I'm using Twitter Bootstrap and `float: left` will show in the same line but the page shows unorganized.

I have something like this ...

```
<div class="col-md-10">
  <h2> Articles <span class="badge"> {{ numArticles }} </span> </h2>
  <div class="col-md-4" ng-repeat="elem in list">
    <h4> {{ elem.title }} </h4>
    <p> {{ elem.desc }} </p>
    <div class="col-sd-4" ng-repeat="it in elem.tags">
      <span class="tagElement">{{ it }}</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The element I need to show in the same line are the `elem.tags`.

Comment: If you are using bootstrap then you should be using `pull-left` and `clearfix` or simply use `display: inline` or `display: inline-block`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned by @Sergiu you can use `display: inline` or use

```
<span class="col-sd-4" ng-repeat="it in elem.tags">
```

instead of.

```
<div class="col-sd-4" ng-repeat="it in elem.tags">
```